# TextView setText appends instead

Tags: android

Hi im trying to set the value of a textview with .setText in a method that is run by a thread but it is being appended to the TextView instead. The parameter String f is a being send to the method in a for loop like this:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        String[] string = array[j].split(":");
        String y= string[0];
        String x= string[1];
        determineSeat(y, something, x);
    }
}

private void determineSeat(String is, String cs, String f)
{
            TextView txtHand = null;
    String txt = null;

    if (iSeat < cSeat) {
        x = cSeat - iSeat;

        if (x == 1) {
            txtHand = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHand8);
            txt = txtHand.getText().toString();
            txtHand.setText("");
            txtHand.setText(txt + ":"  + f);
        }
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand1"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text=" " />
```

I want it to be cleared everytime i put something in the textview instead of being appended anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it to `"txt + ":" + f"`.  `"txt"` is defined as whatever was already in the textview.  If you just want to have it set to `"f"` every time the method is called, do `"txtHand.setText(f);"`  As is, you are asking it to take whatever is currently in the textview, and add a colon and `"f."`

Comment: Started writing after Yosem posted, so I didn't see his post.  Basically, what he said.

Comment: In my opinion, your answer is much more clear and better describes how to solve the problem. You got my vote.

Comment: Thx, for the answer i actually see whats going wrong now its more that i forgot what i was going to do with the txt string. Being busy so long i didnt know what i was doing wrong anymore sorry. This topic has been answerd

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assigning this var the current text:

```
txt = txtHand.getText().toString();
```

And then prepending it to `:f` with this line

```
txtHand.setText(txt + ":"  + f);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because you are initializing a new textbox object evrytime inside the loop and then appending its contents to the new one. You should declare and initialize the textbox outside the loop.

```
TextView txtHand = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHand8);

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        String[] string = array[j].split(":");
        String y= string[0];
        String x= string[1];
        determineSeat(y, something, x);
    }
}

private void determineSeat(String is, String cs, String f)
{
    String txt = null;

    if (iSeat < cSeat) {
        x = cSeat - iSeat;

        if (x == 1) {
            txtHand.setText(":"  + f);
        }
}
```

and what is the string is and cs for